# Cannot list initialize vector with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list, list-initialization

I want to initialize the 2 D vector with values, it gives me this error:

```
IntelliSense: initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>>"
```

What do I get the above error when using the following?

```
vector<vector<int>> A =
    { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
      { 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1 },
      { 0, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2 },
      { 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 },
      { 0, 4, 1, 5, 4, 6 },
      { 0, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3 } };
```

Comment: Note: intellisense is *not* the compiler.

Comment: Compile with support for C++11 or higher.

Comment: [Works just fine here](http://ideone.com/w6ySy3), did you miss the `std::` namespace qualifier?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @DeiDei how to support that version in my visual studio 2012?

Comment: Ah.  VS2012 has little to no C++11 Support.  If you wan to program modern C++ with MSVS use MSVS 2017

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

[MSVS 2012 has very little C++11 support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)  If we look at the linked to MSDN article

[image]

we will see that it does not support initialization lists which is required with the initialization that you are using.

My advice is to upgrade your compiler if you can.  MSVS 2017 has the most complete C++11 support(barring any breaking changes in the newer standards).  If you cannot do that then you can use the pre-C++11 solution of declaring temporary arrays and initializing the vector from the temporary arrays.